# Restart all the pods in deployment in Kubernetes 1.14

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there any kubectl command or script that will restart all pods in a deployment in Kubernetes 1.14. kubectl rollout restart is supported from 1.15. can someone please help

Comment: when i was using 1.15- i used to change env variables to restart pods and update changes. kubectl set env deployment [deployment_name] DEPLOY_DATE="$(date)"

Comment: imho it is much easier to change the DEPLOY_DATE var. it is a one liner per deployment.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator SO added that comment because i marked this question as duplicate. You can add your suggestion as an answer/comment to the linked question so others can see it.

Comment: I noted in the linked question that `kubectl rollout restart`'s action is just to modify a property of the Deployment object and doesn't actually have server-side dependencies; you could probably use the Kubernetes 1.15 `kubectl` (or even 1.24) successfully.